# Resource interpreted as other but transferred with MIME type text/javascript?

Tags: javascript, mime-types, meta-tags

I keep getting "**Resource interpreted as other but transferred with MIME type text/javascript.**", but everything seems to be working fine. This only seems to be happening in Safari 4 on my Mac.

I was advised to add `"meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript"` to the header, although that did nothing.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The most common way to get the error is with the following code:

```
<img src="" class="blah" />
```

A blank url is a shortcut for the current page url, so a duplicate request is made which returns content type html.  The browser is expecting an image, but instead gets html.

Comment: +1 Thanks for that, solved my issue. I would've thought having an empty src, the browser wouldnt load anything... but it still does. Fixed it by adding the src to a spacer.gif

Comment: Woot!! Thank you, this had been bugging me for the longest time.

Comment: This took me 4 hours to track down, and it seems like a Safari bug

Answer (score 3):

i received this error due tu a missing element which a jquery plugin tried to call via js **var btnChange** i commented the none needed (and non existent) images out and the warning (google chrome dev tools) was fixed:

```
$(mopSliderName+" .sliderCaseRight").css({backgroundImage:"url("+btnChange.src+")"});
```

Answer (score 2):

The (webkit-based) browser is issuing a warning that it has decided to ignore the mimetype provided by the webserver - in this case text/javascript - and is applying a different mimetype - in this case "other".

It's a *warning* which users can typically ignore, but a developer might find useful when looking for clues to a problem. For this example it might explain why some javascript wasn't being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is sending the content with a certain MIME type.  For example, a PNG image would be sent with the HTTP header `Content-type: image/png`.  Configure your web server or script to send the proper content type.

Comment: Actually, I researched and I found that it causes no issues. It's something that Safari 4 tends to do... if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

It does cause issues if your are calling a javascript that adds functionality, it is likely to fail, as it does for me. No real answers yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error due to a script with bad permissions bringing up a HTTP 403 error. I gave it read and execute rights across the board and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting for the Apache MIME module where it misses adding the type for javascript, to resolve it, simply open the .htaccess file OR httpd.conf file, add the following lines

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  AddType text/javascript .js
</IfModule>
```

Restart the apache server, issue will be resolved.