# Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: css, html, apache

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv = "Content-Language" content = "en"/>
        <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xxx/app/www/style.css">
```

Now when I load the page, Safari's inspector gives me:

> Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

I'm working on localhost with MAMP. I'm not sure what to modify to get this to work. I read that this might be a server problem of some kind.

How do I solve it?

Comment: similar question( if not exact one) --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text

Comment: Check this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37024887/4762396

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html (seems not related with web server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an `.htaccess` file into your root folder (or update the existing one) with this line inside

```
AddType text/css .css
```

this will tell apache to send the right `content-type` header for `.css` file

Comment: i think the correct way is AddType text/css css

without the dot

Comment: how about on Windows? I am running Django server and this happened to me after I set the Debug flag to False

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility that not just css resources were interpreted wrongly. It maybe a problem of your webserver configuration.

The best way to check is to go to Chrome -> Network tab and check responses section for each request. 
Also you can run `$ curl -I http://path_to_file_or_page` with terminal and have a look at response, you should see it in following format, e.g. `Content-Type: image/jpeg`

---

So, if it will occur that webserver (apache) does it for all filesthen you can try to solve the problem in following way:

Check your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
If there are any `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` line, try to comment it and then reload your apache by `$ sudo system apache2 reload`

Let us know if the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your web server is properly configured but it really is returning HTML instead of CSS.

Check that you have the correct path, spelling, case, etc. Hit the URL directly and see what comes back. Your web server might be responding with an error page (HTML) and a `200-Ok` instead of a `404-Not Found`.

I'm not saying this ever happened to me...