# CSS formatting not working (rackspace cloud static site)

Tags: html, css, rackspace-cloud

I recently uploaded my site for hosting on rackspace cloud, but the CSS formatting is not working at all.

The site works fine on my local drive and when I view the source code from the website via the internet it links correctly to the CSS file, so I know that the link is working.

I have done all of the following, to no avail:
1. Refreshed the cache
2. Opened the site in a different browser (Firefox, Chrome)
3. Validated both the HTML and CSS with W3C validator.
4. Re-uploaded the relevant files (and waited for TTL and refreshed the cache)
5. Contacted rackspace - they said everything looks fine and had no idea what the problem was

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How are we supposed to help without even so much as a link to the site, let alone [an SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the lack of code. I figured if it was validated that should be sufficient (also I did not want to link the site). I suspected it was a server problem and it turns out that was the case (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess, but the same thing happened to me. Try: [Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553638/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html)

Also check your debugger console (good advice in general) to see if that error pops up.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That was exactly the problem. I figured it was a server problem, but I would have never thought to use the debugger. Just a note, however, uploading the .htaccess file to rackspace has to be done through an ftp (not the gui).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to load just the linked css url in a browser to verify that the link is correct

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Actually I have already done this (see "view the source code from the website via the internet" in my question above). The link was correct - apparently it was a server problem where the file was being passed as an html file even though it was listed as css.