# Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html (seems not related with web server)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have this problem. Chrome continues to return this error

> Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

The files affected by this error are just the Style, chosen and jquery-gentleselect (other CSS files that are imported in the index in the same way work well and without error). I've already checked my MIME type and text/css is already on CSS.

Honestly I'd like to start by understanding the problem (a thing that seems I cannot do alone).

Comment: Can you provide the URL of this stylesheet?

Comment: Just in case someone needs this. This was happening to me due to the compression of the css file. And somehow after two times of compression, one in local, one from my CDN provider, the server can not recognize it anymore.

Comment: This happened to me when a stylesheet tag's request was being redirected on the server because of an ordering issue of middleware (auth middleware before static file serving). The error message in the console `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/login".
login:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` showed the redirected page url instead of the original css request which made it a little hard to track down.

Comment: I too experienced what @vaughan ran into. It was because the stylesheet required authentication . . . on a page that was trying to perform authentication. Really hard issue to troubleshoot, but once you figure it out, it seems pretty obvious.

Comment: A lot of people has added different solutions to this issue in different environments.  
I had to scroll a lot before finding mine (Reactjs).  
Don't give up if you don't find your's near the top as is usual in SO.

Comment: Could you please add the comment you made at Mar 25 '14 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see#comment34466303_22631253) to this actual question?

Comment: I was using custom .htaccess for URL beautification, so i put a new .htaccess in my assets directory with one line 

**RewriteEngine Off** and got it solved, hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

> i'd like to start by understanding the problem

Browsers make HTTP requests to servers. The server then makes an HTTP response.

Both requests and responses consist of a bunch of headers and a (sometimes optional) body with some content in it.

If there is a body, then one of the headers is the `Content-Type` which describes what the body is (is it an HTML document? An image? The contents of a form submission? etc).

When you ask for your stylesheet, your server is telling the browser that it is an HTML document (`Content-Type: text/html`) instead of a stylesheet (`Content-Type: text/css`).

> I've already checked my myme.type and text/css is already on css.

Then something else about your server is making that stylesheet come with the wrong content type.

Use the Net tab of your browser's developer tools to examine the request and the response.

Comment: i think that im pretty sure that the problem is in my .htaccess wich is http://pastebin.com/w8UnqFs8 (i forgot to mention that this error is giving me only in subdirectory and only after a page refresh). Thanks for your explanation, was pretty helpful for understanding the problem. :)

Comment: Make sure that you can access the file without logging in.

Comment: @Max why don't you put that info in the actual question? :)

Answer (score 105):

**Using Angular?**

This is a very important caveat to remember.

The base tag needs to not only be in the head but in the right location.

I had my base tag in the wrong place in the head, it should come before any tags with url requests. Basically placing it as the second tag underneath the title solved it for me.

```
<base href="/">
```

I wrote a little post on it [here](http://powdertothepeople.tv/2016/11/20/Resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-MIME-type-text-html/)

Comment: using `ng-href` instead of `href` solved it for me !

Comment: I was getting OTS parsing error: invalid version tag instead, but found this when looking for a solution and oh my god, this saved me.

Comment: In my case, I was using an .htaccess rewrite rule to change a directory to a query string variable, like such: `RewriteRule ^my_dir/(.+)$ /new_dir/?my_var=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Like Max, this fixed my issue despite the fact that I'm not using Angular.  I placed the offending link/href first, in front of all other links, in my head section-- and the warning disappeared.

Comment: might want to rename your title in your  article. I don't even use Angular. Im using Swift + Leaf and this solved my problem.

Comment: I think this is the case for most SPAs. This worked for my pure JS SPA (no framework).

Answer (score 48):

I also had problem with this error, and came upon a solution. This does not explain why the error occurred, but it seems to fix it in some cases.

Include a forward slash  **/**  before the path to the css file, like so:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: is this relevant in this case ?

Comment: I had lose to much time on this small mistake. If someone will read my answer and it will help him it will be relevant in this case.

Comment: What actually happened is the server served the file on `/css/bootstrap.min.css` , but when you did not included the `/` it just looks it in the current directory, for example if you went to `yoursite.com/hello/trilochan` , it will then looks under `hello/css/bootsrap.min.css` , but it is really under `yoursite.com/css/bootsrap.min.css`, I hope I cleared this, `/` refers to root, and without `/` , it looks in current directory.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet It was very much relevant, I had the same problem.

Comment: I would highly recommend to you web developer bootcamp on udemy by colt steele, it will help you clear your doubts.

Comment: This worked for me, I have no idea why but it did. I ran into this problem on one particular page out of many using EJS. No idea why that one page had the problem and the others didn't.

Comment: What did the trick for me was adding ```type="text/css"``` to the tag.

Answer (score 22):

My issue was simpler than all the answers in this post.

I had to setup IIS to include static content.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Setting the Anonymous Authentication Credentials to **Application Pool Identity** did the trick for me.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Try this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../##/yourcss.css">`

where `##` is your folder wherein is your .CSS - file

Don't forget about the: `..` (double dots).

Comment: I added double dots and slash(../file_path). it worked for me. thanks

Comment: What's the reason of adding these two `..`

Comment: Yikes, such a simple overlooked mistake, mine was just pointing to wrong path.

Using ```..``` just goes up 1 directory.

Answer (score 9):

I was also facing the same problem. And after doing some R&D, I found that the problem was with the file name. The name of the actual file was **"lightgallery.css"** but while linking I has typed **"lightGallery.css"**.

**More Info:**

It worked well on my localhost (OS: Windows 8.1 & Server: Apache).
But when I uploaded my application to a remote server ( Different OS & Web server than than my localhost) it didn't work, giving me the same error as yours.

So, the issue was the case sensitivity (with respect to file names) of the server.

Answer (score 9):

In case you serve static css with nginx you should add

```
location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}
location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}
```

or

```
location ~ \.css{
    default_type text/css;
}
location ~ \.js{
    default_type application/x-javascript;
}
```

to nginx conf

Answer (score 8):

Based on the other answers it seems like this message has a lot of causes, I thought I'd just share my individual solution in case anyone has my exact problem in the future.

Our site loads the CSS files from an AWS Cloudfront distribution, which uses an S3 bucket as the origin. This particular S3 bucket was kept synced to a Linux server running Jenkins. The `sync` command via `s3cmd` sets the Content-Type for the S3 object automatically based on what the OS says (presumably based on the file extension). For some reason, in our server, all the types were being set correctly except `.css` files, which it gave the type `text/plain`. In S3, when you check the metadata in the properties of a file, you can set the type to whatever you want. Setting it to `text/css` allowed our site to correctly interpret the files as CSS and load correctly.

Answer (score 5):

@Rob Sedgwick's answer gave me a pointer, However, in my case my app was a **Spring Boot Application**. So I just added exclusions in my Security Config for the paths to the concerned files...

***NOTE - This solution is SpringBoot-based... What you may need to do might differ based on what programming language you are using and/or what framework you are utilizing***

However the point to note is;

> Essentially the problem can be caused when every request, including
>   those for static content are being authenticated.

So let's say some paths to my static content which were causing the errors are as follows;

***A path called "plugins"***

> http://localhost:8080/plugins/styles/css/file-1.css
>
> http://localhost:8080/plugins/styles/css/file-2.css
>
> http://localhost:8080/plugins/js/script-file.js

***And a path called "pages"***

> http://localhost:8080/pages/styles/css/style-1.css
>
> http://localhost:8080/pages/styles/css/style-2.css
>
> http://localhost:8080/pages/js/scripts.js

Then I just add the exclusions as follows in my Spring Boot Security Config;

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(<comma separated list of other permitted paths>, "/plugins/**", "/pages/**").permitAll()
            // other antMatchers can follow here
    }

}
```

---

***Excluding these paths `"/plugins/**"` and `"/pages/**"` from authentication made the errors go away.***

---

Cheers!

Comment: @Ben Rhys-Lewis... I wonder why you think this is a Question or even looks like one for that matter. Perhaps, you want to read my answer carefully enough to see that it's actually an ANSWER - alas, one which worked in my case... and is definitely NOT a Question.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I am not sure how that happened, I made a boo-boo. Please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 4):

**Using Angular**

In my case using `ng-href` instead of `href` solved it for me.

**Note :**

I am working with laravel as back-end

Comment: But where to add this ?

Comment: in the link tag

Answer (score 4):

If you are on JSP, this problem can come from your servlet mapping.
if your mapping takes url by defaut like this:

```
@WebServlet("/")
```

then the container interpret your css url, and goes to the servlet instead of going to the css file.

i had the same issue, i changed my mapping and now everyting works

Answer (score 3):

i was facing the same thing, with sort of the same .htaccess file for making pretty urls. after some hours of looking around and experimenting. i found out that the error was because of relatively linking files.

the browser will start fetching the same source html file for all the css, js and image files, when i would browse a few steps deep into the server.

to counter this you can either use the `<base>` tag on your html source,

```
<base href="http://localhost/assets/">
```

and link to files like,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

or use absolute links for all your files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/assets/css/style.css" />
<script src="http://localhost/assets/js/script.js"></script>
<img src="http://localhost/assets/images/logo.png" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem in MVC4 using forms authentication. The problem was this line in the web.config,

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

This means that every request, including those for static content, being authenticated.

Change this line to:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]
I also face this problem recently on **chrome**. I just give absolute path to my CSS file problem solve.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=SS_URL?>arica/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: You've got to be effing kidding me. Dismissed this solution like 3 times. Came on this page multiple times but after trying everything else and about to give up, I said: "heck what could go wrong". It worked!!!                                                 Mystery of life

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that might be having this issue.
I was building a custom MVC in PHP when I encountered this issue.

I was able to resolve this by setting my assets (css/js/images) files to an absolute path.
Instead of using url like href="css/style.css" which use this entire current url to load it. As an example, if you are in http://example.com/user/5, it will try to load at http://example.com/user/5/css/style.css.

To fix it, you can add a / at the start of your asset's url (i.e. href="/css/style.css"). This will tell the browser to load it from the root of your url. In this example, it will try to load http://example.com/css/style.css.

Hope this comment will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you must have set content type as text/html instead of text/css for your server page (php,node.js etc)

Comment: this problem was regarding a css file, not an html one

Answer (score 1):

I want to expand on Todd R's point in the OP. In asp.net pages, the `web.config` file defines permissions needed to access each file or folder in the application. In our case, the folder of CSS files did not allow access for unauthorized users, causing it to fail on the login page before the user was authorized. Changing the required permissions in `web.config` allowed unauthorized users to access the CSS files and solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exact problem and after a few minutes fooling around I deciphered that I missed to add the file extension to my header. so I changed the following line :

```
<link uic-remove rel="stylesheet" href="css/bahblahblah">
```

to

```
<link uic-remove rel="stylesheet" href="css/bahblahblah.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using React**

I came across this error in my react profile app. My app behaved kind of like it was trying to reference a url that doesn't exist. I believe this has something to do with how webpack behaves.

If you are linking files in your public folder you must remember to use %PUBLIC_URL% before the resource like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes to this post and has a similar issue.  I just experienced a similar problem, but the solution was quite simple.

A developer had mistakenly dropped a copy of the web.config into the CSS directory.  Once deleted, all errors were resolved and the page properly displayed.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit Gupta for the edit.  I was typing faster than my internal grammar manager would process! =)

Comment: This is an ASP.NET-specific solution, which is no obvious part of the question.

Comment: @dakab so what? A lot of the other answers are framework-specific too, and they've helped people using those frameworks that are experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue whilst resuming work on a old MEAN stack project. I was using `nodemon` as my local development server and got the same error `Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`. I changed from `nodemon` to `http-server` which can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). It immediately worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred when I removed the protocol from the css link for a css stylesheet served by a google CDN.

This gives no error:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter">
```

But this gives the error *Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html* :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue. And Exploring solutions in this fantastic Stack Overflow page.

user54861 's response (mismatching names in case sensetivity) makes me curious to inspect my code again and realized that "**I didnt upload two js files that I loaded them in head tag**". :-)

When I uploaded them the issue runs away ! And code runs and page rendered without any another error!

So, moral of the story is don't forget to make sure that all of your js files are uploaded where the page is looking for them.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16751300)

Comment: Can't be a clue to ecma script designers to add a relevant error or exception to javascript if developer didnt load resource to server?
I mean "Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html" is confusing a bit, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue with a .NET application, a CMS open-source called MojoPortal. In one of my themes and skin for a particular site, when browsing or testing it would grind and slow down like it was choking.

My issue was not of the "type" attribute for the CSS but it was "that other thing". My exact change was in the **Web.Config**. I changed all the values to FALSE for MinifyCSS, CacheCssOnserver, and CacheCSSinBrowser.

Once that was set the web site was speedy once again in production.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error because I forgot to send a correct header a first

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
print 'body { text-align: justify; font-size: 2em; }';
```

Answer (score 0):

If **nodejs** and using **express** 
the below code works...

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
```

Comment: Commenting on here because it's related to Node.JS . I had to restart the app on my hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when loading CSS for a React layout module that I installed with npm. You have to import two .css files to get this module running, so I initially imported them like this:

```
@import "../../../../node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
```

but found out that the file extension has to be dropped, so this worked:

```
@import "../../../../node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles";
```

Answer (score 0):

I started to get the issue today only on chrome and not safari for the same project/url for my goormide container (node.js)

After trying several suggestions above which didn't appear to work and backtracking on some code changes I made from yesterday to today which also made no difference I ended up in the chrome settings clicking:

1.Settings;

2.scroll down to bottom, select: "Advanced";

3.scroll down to bottom, select: "Restore settings to their original defaults";

That appears to have fixed the problem as I no longer get the warning/error in the console and the page displays as it should. Reading the posts above it appears the issue can occur from any number of sources so the settings reset is a potential generic fix.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving the app in prod make sure you are serving the static files with service worker. I had this error when I was serving only static subfolder of React build on Django (without assets that have styles)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while configuring Postfix Admin 3.2. According to the official documentation, the whole Postfix Admin content should be extracted into a separate directory, i.e. `/srv/postfixadmin` and not the document root. Only the `/srv/postfixadmin/public` directory should be symlinked into `/var/www/html` document root. I have just extracted the whole content into `/var/www/html`. Having played with Nginx server block settings, I managed example.com/postfixadmin resolving from `/var/www/html/postfixadmin/public`. Nevertheless, images and CSS were not available with 404 status code. The stylesheets were broken. I got the error message OP quoted with respective 404 entries in access log.

In my case, I just moved `/var/www/html/postfixadmin` into `/srv/postfixadmin` and made `ln -s /srv/postfixadmin/public /var/www/html/postfixadmin` . This solved the issue completely.
Here is the [reference](https://github.com/postfixadmin/postfixadmin/blob/master/INSTALL.TXT#L61).

Answer (score -1):

Using ReactJs, when I add style file to index.html using relative link such as

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">`

and then I navigate to a route say; `localhost:3000/artist` and refresh, I get the error.

The error disappeared after I replaced the relative link with an absolute link say;

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/project/public/css/style.css"`.

Comment: I had this issue, same environment, and tried your solution with no luck. But you showed me a research path  :-)  
The messages disappeared after I moved the CSS files to the public folder. Once I did there was no need for the absolute paths.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, same error was coming with JSP. This is how I got to the root of this issue:  I went to the Network tab and clearly saw that the browser request to fetch the css was returning response header having "Content-type" : "text/html". I opened another tab and manually hit the request to fetch the css. It ended up returning a html log in form. Turns out that my web application had a url mapping for path = `/` Tomcat servlet entry : `(@WebServlet({  "/, /index", })`. So, any unmatching request URLs were somehow being matched to `/` and the corresponding servlet was returning a Log in html form. I fixed it by removing the mapping to `/`

Also, the tomcat configuration wrt handling css MIME-TYPE was already present.

Comment: Would like to know why this answer was downvoted ? It can surely help someone to debug, if they face similar issue.

Answer (score -2):

Answer might be given above. I had the same problem and couldn't resolve it. Make it sure to add `external js` file as

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```