# Unable to link CSS File in a sample MVC

Tags: php, css

I am trying to implement a Sample MVC(PHP) in which  CSS file  doesn't seem to be working . i Suspect it could be my referring style .
The below code is of header from views

Views-> header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="public/css/default.css">

</head>
<body >
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
    <p>dsfds</p>
```

css file   Public/CSS/Default.css

```
body {
    background: silver;
}
```

For clear picture this is my folder structure

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Try ../public/css/default.css

Comment: There is an htaccess which may have rewrite rules so url can be different from your structure. I will prefer you to use absolute url insted of relative. This will work for you.

Comment: @aman rawat Indeed it was .htacess at the end that was causing issues. Apparently file was being detected with issue "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:"   had to rewrite htaccess that fixed the issue.

Comment: Solution for this issue was found in the below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see

by using the code from this source .http://pastebin.com/w8UnqFs8

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="../public/css/default.css">
</head>
...
```

Comment: i have tried it . but still the same problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Your code is starting at header.php and now looking for /public/css/default.css.

In this case you would need your file to be in views/public/css/default.css

Try changing your code to

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/default.css">

</head>
<body >
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
    <p>dsfds</p>
```

by adding the `..` prior to the location of the file it tells it that it needs to take one step back (putting you in the root directory) and than to look for /public/css/default.css

Edit: Make sure you're switching src = " " to href = " ".

Comment: i have tried it . but still the same problem persists

Comment: @Arun3x3 including the switch from src = "" to href = "" ?

Comment: I haven't even noticed src instead of href. this could be a part of the problem too. try this answer

Comment: i had to rewrite .htacess  as i see that was causing the issue.

Comment: @Arun3x3 Great! Glad to see you figured it out, please update your question with an answer to help the next person who stumbles onto this!

Answer (score 0):

The path should be from the index file not from the header. the header.php is just like copy and paste text into the index.php

use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../public/css/default.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/default.css">
```

depending on which index.php file you are at, the one inside the views folder or the one on the sourceFiles folder.

Hope this helps.