# JSP Tomcat7 static css and js files not loading

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, tomcat

Learning JSP and have an issue with the css/js content not loading. I have a jsp page, where I have bootstrap css and js referenced using standard html link and script tags:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" link="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

and

```
<script src="/WebIntro/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

neither of them work and Chrome is giving me the following on the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain:
```

If I use an include directive, it works for the css but pulls all the content into the file:

```
<%@include file="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"%>
```

The jsp has the following @page and meta tags:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" %>
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Language" content = "en"/>
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I tried googling and found the mime-mapping element for the web.xml but the following seems to have no affect:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>js</extension>
    <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

If there is some standard Tomcat config that needs to happen I am unaware as I am new to Tomcat; using Tomcat 7, and eclipse and this is in a maven project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was very strange. The changes to the web.xml file that was present since I built the project in eclipse/maven, weren't reflected in the web.xml within tomcat webapp application directories. Everything else in the package updates fine (as far as I can tell), except for the web.xml?

So I found the web.xml file within eclipse inside target >> project-SNAPSHOT >> WEB-INF >> web.xml (which is supposed to be derived). Forced changes there and it worked, changes were picked up and my original issue gone.

I am guessing I had inadvertently broken some type of dependency link or something along the way somehow, but once I added the servlet, mappings, etc back in, everything worked fine.

Weird.

Answer (score -1):

Removing this line in jsp resolved the error for us.
We were facing the issue when using Tomcat 8.5.59