# Bootstrap Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am unable to load bootstrap on web page.

I am getting following error.

> **Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:**
>       `http://localhost:86/Content/bootstrap/?v=LopV7sR0PywufK81-SuWkZQzYBDxpce17ye48bBkprE1`

I have bundled the all the scripts and css as follows

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
         "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
          "~/Scripts/Custom/DatePickerReady.js",
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
          "~/Scripts/respond.matchmedia.addListener.js",
          "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Controls").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/checkbox.js",
                 "~/Scripts/dropdownlist.js",
                 "~/Scripts/textbox.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/grid").Include(
                "~/Scripts/gridmvc.datepicker.js",
                "~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/MvcGrid/mvc-grid.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/custom-grid.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
    // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/resize").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/benalman.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ScrollSaver").Include("~/Scripts/scrollsaver.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Site").Include(
                "~/Scripts/Site.js"));


    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
             "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
             "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/grid").Include(
             "~/Content/MvcGrid/mvc-grid.css",
             "~/Content/Gridmvc.css",
             "~/Content/gridmvc.datepicker.min.css"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
             "~/Content/site-mobile.css",
             "~/Content/site-web.css"));
```

and render them in following sequence

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Site")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/grid")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Controls")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/resize")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

I had given the all the read, write execute permissions to the folder. Instead of that files in the path "~/content/bootstrap/" is not accessible. When I opens the link in new tab it shows the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAAxs.jpg)

Please point where I am going wrong.

Further, it is happening only when I deploy my application IIS. When I run the application from Visual Studio the bootstrap get loaded properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html (seems not related with web server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see)

Comment: i already considered the post mention by Bharat Gupta. but unable to resolve the issue

Comment: did you manage to fix this please?