# jsp file is not reflecting the styles in bootstrap

Tags: css, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have jsp file and trying to load bootstrap.min.css there, both files(jsp and bootstrap) are in the same directory which is webapp and this is the code that I use to link jsp and bootstrap.css together.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
```

But the jsp is not reflecting any style that the bootstrap contain and this is the problem that I got.

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see

Comment: put / and try agian. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: I got these errors
hotel:6 GET http://localhost:8080/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
hotel:7 GET http://localhost:8080/bootstrap-grid.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
hotel:9 GET http://localhost:8080/hotel.css net::ERR_ABORTED
hotel:8 GET http://localhost:8080/bootstrap-reboot.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED

Comment: please note that this work, but I want to load it from my code .. <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: Copy CSS files to the root.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved when I changed the code in the web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>hotel-deals</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>hotel-deals</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/hotel</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```