# "Resource interpreted as stylesheet" "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, apache2

I was not able to reload pages in my React app (got 404 error), so I had to add the following to my apache conf file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

After that change the errors shown in the image appeared:

[image]

I have already seen a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see)

But none of the answers related to ReactJS work for me. This has clearly to do with my css files. I am currently storing them in a css folder under the src folder in my project.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Have you added any external stylesheets?

Comment: Try this .htaccess - `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
RewriteRule . index.html [L]`

Comment: these are my css imports: import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import '../css/myCss.css'; The rewrite code you suggested gives an error: "Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by changing the Rewrite code from:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js|map)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```