# VideoJS CSS Loading from CloudFlare CDN Reports "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain"

Tags: css, mime-types, cdn, cloudflare

Since I began working with the Video.js package, I have noticed the following message in the Microsoft Edge Chromium debugger window.

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain

After reviewing the link tag in the head section of my document, I rewrote it as follows.

```
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css"
      type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

However, the message persists to this day. Hence, my investigation, leading to this inquiry. My investigation included careful reviews of other SO topics, including [Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see)

Following the suggestion made in the article cited above, I discovered the following, none of which gives me any actionable clues.

GENERAL:

Request URL: https://unpkg.com/video.js@7.11.4/dist/video-js.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: 104.16.126.175:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

REQUEST HEADERS:

:authority: unpkg.com
:method: GET
:path: /video.js@7.11.4/dist/video-js.css
:scheme: https
accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
dnt: 1
referer: https://purl.salestalktech.com/
sec-fetch-dest: style
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.68

RESPONSE HEADERS:

access-control-allow-origin: *
age: 1556501
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
cf-cache-status: HIT
cf-ray: 621108492ec5c7ee-DFW
cf-request-id: 083e8381be0000c7eec1064000000001
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8
date: Sat, 13 Feb 2021 19:42:24 GMT
etag: W/"b11c-eNA12vzR+gkTx6x94xGmXeYYKoY"
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
last-modified: Sat, 26 Oct 1985 08:15:00 GMT
server: cloudflare
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cloud-trace-context: 131511d3829f15c61542a490bfcfec94
x-content-type-options: nosniff

REQUEST INITIATOR CHAIN:

https://purl.salestalktech.com/SalesAcceleration/Repository/SalesRelevance/Assets/VideoPlayer/demo/YouTube_Event_Sinks_CodePen.HTML
https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css
https://unpkg.com/video.js@7.11.4/dist/video-js.css

Suggestions are welcome, and all hailing frequencies are open.

Comment: One of the comments in [Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see) suggests that the HTTP 302 redirect shown in ![VJS_CSS_in_Network_Tab](https://purl.salestalktech.com/SalesAcceleration/Repository/SalesRelevance/Assets/VideoPlayer/demo/VJS_CSS_in_Network_Tab_20210213_152813.png) might have a bearing on the issue at hand. However, since that redirect could change at any time, I am reluctant to change it. Thoughts?

Comment: So which do you use on your page in the end? https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css which returns `text/plain` or https://unpkg.com/video.js@7.11.4/dist/video-js.css which results in correct `text/css`?