# External css path is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Ix7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrj3O.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP0y2.png)

I'm facing this issue I can't figure out what is wrong here I'm doing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: hm this might be out of topic but, may i know why you are using nodejs when you can just use only HTML and CSS?

Comment: I want to build full stack app here using nodejs express framework.

Comment: And no errors are coming the file is not recognizing

Answer (score 1):

Check if the CSS file is in the same folder as the page.
Check if using relative or absolute path is suitable ( .\ and ..*** for navigation)
Open the page in browser-> developer tools->network and check if it is loading.

Comment: css file is in same folder I had attached screenshots for reference

Comment: Please check if removing the "text/css" in the code resolves the issue. I think the server inproperly returns it as "text/html" instead of "text/css". I think that you have to check the web server. I think the following  SO thread is for this issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see