# Stylesheet missing in silverstipe website

Tags: silverstripe

I recently installed silverstripe3.1.4, but after installation, I am able to see the website, but the style are missing when I request mysite.com

Then I requested mysite.com/about-us, error page is displayed, but the style are applied

But when mysite.com/index.php/about-us/ is requested says, No input file specified.

Comment: Could you provide the site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553638/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html

Try this question on the forum,when checking your console you can see the error message. I can see double CSS-stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS stylesheets are being returned as text/html which is why they're not applying any styles.

The reason this is happening is because the request is being passed through the framework. Instead of /themes/simple/css/reset.css its requesting /index.php/themes/simple/css/reset.css.

http://dev.taputeranga.maori.nz/index.php/themes/simple/css/reset.css (text/html)
http://dev.taputeranga.maori.nz/themes/simple/css/reset.css (text/css)

To fix this you should use `<% require themedCSS("reset") %>` in your template for all stylesheets instead of your current method.

Also, slightly unrelated, but if you want to get rid of the /index.php/ in your links you should rename the index.php or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I recenlty came across link on silverstripe forum, the solution is to remove index.php

reference
http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/23637

Thanks Tim and Mic