# Changing MIME type with Meteor

Tags: css, meteor, mime

When I'm running my app on localhost, I get 2 warnings concerning MIME type. This is one of them:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/BootstrapEssentials/bootstrap.css".`

The other warning is identical with a different file. Both files are in my working directory. So far, I have been to these similar questions but they haven't helped:

[Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html (seems not related with web server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see)

[Chrome says "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.", what gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text)

[Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553638/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html)

Originally I was trying to use this line:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/BootstrapEssentials/bootstrap.css">`

I have since added in the type field:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/BootstrapEssentials/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">`

but that didn't do anything. I also have used the JavaScript Console to see that in the response header it has `content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8` and I believe that if I can change that to being `content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8` then everything will be fine but I can't find how to do that either.

Comment: Is the BootstrapEssentials folder in a directory named public?

Comment: @sheeldotme no, should it be? I currently have it in the clients folder alongside my client.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Meteor docs:

> All files inside a top-level directory called public/ are served as-is to the client. When referencing these assets, do not include public/ in the URL, write the URL as if they were all in the top level. For example, reference public/bg.png as /bg.png. This is the best place for favicon.ico, robots.txt, and similar files.

Moving your stylesheets to a directory in public should do the trick!