# Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html - Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, mime-types, meta-tags

In my angular app, I'm using an upload field and is showing the thumbnail of the uploaded image below the file field. The images gets uploaded and the thumbnails are displayed, but sometimes the thumbnail is not been displayed and at that time I'm getting this error `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html`

But the same image may work sometime and may not some other time. Is this the issue with `.httaccess` ?

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /foldername/
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     .               index.html              [L]
```

Comment: look in network tab of browser console to see exactly what is returned including headers.

Comment: In the response header I got Content-Type:text/html

Comment: but what is returned in body? And what is status? My guess is a 404 page or something like that

Comment: angular is loading the background of the project and then the browsers hangs up..

Comment: This happens to me as well.  Curious whether you were able to find a solution to this.  I've tried several things, like setting new content-type headers, switching my div tags to an object and setting the content-type there, but still getting text/html.  Works fine in localhost but not when deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-src` for images if you are using any angular expressions for image URL's.

Otherwise the browser will see funky URL's like:

```
<img src="{{image.url}}">
```

And will attempt to make requests to paths that obviously can't resolve.

The following however won't have an `src` until angular creates it with a resolved expression

```
<img ng-src="{{image.url}}"> <!-- browser sees no "src" yet therefore doesn't make a request -->
```

Comment: But for the failed images, even if I open the image in browser, ie like http://example.com/foldername/images/imagename.png, the image is not loaded instead it just shows the background image of the website.

Answer (score 0):

A fact that:

> ...**but sometimes the thumbnail is NOT been displayed** and at that time I'm getting this error Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html...

Should be answered here: [Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14234710/1679310)

*(A cite form the answer which does fit to the above scenario)*

> This might well occur if your image path is set incorrectly. For example relative to current directory "images/myimage.gif" vs relative to web root "/images/myimage.gif".
>
> **The reference to "text/html" might suggest you have an error being returned by the server.**

As charlietfl pointed out, it depends, when the url is ready. In angular, it could be a bit later, than the `<img src=""` is touched/executed by DOM. So to make it - waiting for url being ready - change it to **`ng-src`**

Comment: The path provided in src is like "http://example.com/foldername/images/imagename.png"

Comment: I would say, that our issue here is - 1) image path is correct (good) 2) but as my answer says: the server is provided with wrong path. How it could happen? the url to image is set later... e.g. once $http does load that. Or some model.imagUrl is resolved. And that's where we can use angular feature ng-src... hope it helps ;)