# Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html for background image

Tags: jquery, css

All,
I know this question has been asked and probably the one most relevant to my question is this one:

[Resource interpreted as other but transferred with MIME type text/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386312/resource-interpreted-as-other-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-javascript)

My situation is that I have a background image that has some jquery attached to it to display a mobile menu. This currently doesn't work on iPad/iPhones. I'm using the Developer Tools in Chrome to basically mirror and iPhone 5 display to recreate the error so I can see the errors in the console.

The warning I keep getting is the Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html.

The code that populates the menu entries is as follows:

```
<nav id="mobile-menu-container" role="navigation" class="site-navigation mobile-navigation">
<ul id="mobile-menu-dropdown"><li>Browse</li></ul>
<div class="menu-mobile-menu-container">
<ul id="mobile-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-122">
<a href="http://website.com/">Home</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>  
</nav>
```

I think have the following CSS:

```
#mobile-menu-container {
padding: 0;
float: none;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}

#mobile-menu-container #mobile-menu-dropdown {
display: block;
}

#mobile-menu-container #mobile-menu-dropdown li {
cursor: pointer;
margin-right: 0;
background: url('../images/menu.png?1350393124') center right no-repeat;
border-top: none;
}
```

I think the line that is causing me issues is this one:

```
background: url('../images/menu.png?1350393124') center right no-repeat;
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you appending that string to the png item anyway?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No real reason, it was delivered that way with the theme for Wordpress. It worked like that in the demo.

Comment: Are you sure that was included in the file in and of its self? To me, that looks like a random time stamp appended to prevent caching, but instead, you've hard-coded it directly.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I think its actually the menu id that is generated from wordpress.

Comment: Can you remove the string and see if your error goes away....

Comment: It does look like the warning goes away with this. However, my menu still doesn't drop down. That might have to be a different question though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29139/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-user1048676)